# MVC 5 return multiple tables to index action result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I am having an issue where I need to return multiple tables to a view. As of now, my index action result only obtains one table, but this needs to be modified.

Here's the code for the controller:

```
public class ResidentialBuildingController : Controller
{
    private BIRDSResidentialEntities db = new BIRDSResidentialEntities();

    // GET: ResidentialBuilding
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.ResidentialBuildings.ToList());
        //return View();
    }
```

As of now it is returning only db.ResidentialBuildings. I also need it to return db.ResidentialLocations and other tables. Please do let me know.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code for the ResidenitialBuilding view:

```
@model BIRDS.ViewModel.BuildingViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ResidentialBuilding";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("ResidentialBuildingType", new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.type).Distinct()), "Select Building Type")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select id="ResidentialBuildingStories" name="ResidentialBuildingStories"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select id="ResidentialBuildingSize" name="ResidentialBuildingSize"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-round" id="info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click for more info">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="bldgInfo">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="titles">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" id="values">
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for ViewModel :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BIRDS.Models;

namespace BIRDS.ViewModel
{
    public class BuildingViewModel
    {
        public List<ResidentialBuilding> ResidentialBuildings { get; set; }
        public List<ResidentialLocation> ResidentialLocations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The BuildingViewModel is located in a folder called ViewModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a ViewModel:

```
public Class BuildingViewModel
{

public List<ResidentialBuilding> ResidentialBuildings {get;set;}

public List<ResidentialLocation> ResidentialLocations {get;set;}

}
```

and now in controller:

```
public class ResidentialBuildingController : Controller
{
    private BIRDSResidentialEntities db = new BIRDSResidentialEntities();

    // GET: ResidentialBuilding
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BuildingViewModel model = new BuildingViewModel();
        model.ResidentialBuildings  = db.ResidentialBuildings.ToList();
        model.ResidentialLocations  = db.ResidentialLocations.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and strongly type your view with this view model:

```
@model YourNameSpace.ViewModels.BuildingViewModel
```

For more details you can refer following links:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/QHQT270712-Understanding-ViewModel-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html

http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html

http://www.edandersen.com/2013/05/30/asp-net-mvc-basics-part-2-viewmodel-to-model-mapping-and-editing/

Comment: Well, I add the line `@model BIRDS.ViewModel.BuildingViewModel;` to the views, but it returns this error:
**Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement** Not entirely sure what's going on now.

Comment: Yes. But there is a new error. How do I show you my view? Should I update the question with the new code for the view?

Comment: yes show the view and view model as well and in which folder you have added?

Comment: Done. Literally hundreds of lines of my code is not working now!

Comment: Yes. The error I get know is in reference to the Model.Select function in ResidentialBuilding.cshtml. The error is as follows:
**CS1061: 'BIRDS.ViewModel.BuildingViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'BIRDS.ViewModel.BuildingViewModel' could be found**

Comment: your model is now different, you have ``ResidentialBuilidings`` inside Model,so  for selecting from ``ResidentialBuilidings`` you have to do :``Model.ResidentialBuilidings.Select(x => x.type)``